# Переменная в C#

Tags: c#

Учусь C#, читаю чужой код и возник вопрос, что обозначают `{0}` таким символом, это элемент массива?
Вот весь кусок

```
 string uri = string.Format(@"http://{0}/IntegrationServices/WorkWithLoadResource/ShippingLoad", ServerName);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Это специальная конструкция для форматной строки, имеет смысл только там (ну и ещё в паре функций). На её место будет подставлен 1-ый аргумент `string.Format`, считая от нуля. В вашем случае — `ServerName`. Если на месте `ServerName` окажется не строка, будет вызван `.ToString()` для получения строки.

На место `{1}`, аналогично, будет подставлен второй аргумент и т. д.